# Trouble after deleting Linux partitions

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu

I have a laptop that I was dual booting with Windows 7 and Ubuntu. I used the MSFT disk manager to delete the partitions. I made sure my windows live cd was working, which it was, before doing this. But now, when I boot my computer, it won't run the cd. All I get is

`error: no such partition.` and then a command prompt: `grub rescue>`

I made sure my boot priority was set to boot from the CD first...

What can I do!?

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work. Had to go into BIOS and enable "F12 for Boot Menu." This enabled me to boot from the Live CD. Thank God!! Pheeeew!

Answer (score 1):

That was a temporary quick fix.  Generally I select my booting order in the BIOS.

1. USB HDD
2. USB other drives
3. DVD/ CD drive
4. Hard Disk.

It does slow the initial boot time, but I so regularly change my boot systems, I don't mind the extra seconds.

Comment: It's actually not working because the Live CD "is not compatible with my system." I tried another Live CD and it didn't detect any problems. I'm screwed!